# Update column in set of records only if multiple rows exist with a given value in a different field?

Tags: sql, oracle

My_Table would be something like this:

```
user_id  shared_field  bool_field
-------  ------------  ----------
1        abc           null
2        def           null
3        ghi           Y
4        ghi           null
5        ghi           null
6        abc           Y
7        jkl           null
```

If the bool_field changes for a user who shares the same shared_field with other users (such as user_id 3, 4, and 5 above), only that one user should have a 'Y'. The rest should have null values in the bool_field column. For example, if user_id 4 should now have the 'Y', I have to change user_id 4's bool_field to 'Y', and ensure that user_id 3 and 5 have bool_field values of null.

If the user doesn't share a shared_field value with anyone else, then that bool_field should be null (as in user_id 1 and 2 above).

**Update:** added a couple of lines to show that multiple user_ids could share a given shared_field (eg, 1 and 6 both have 'abc'; 3, 4, and 5 all have 'ghi' - only one 'abc' user should have a 'Y', and only one 'ghi' user should have a 'Y' and so on, while the rest have null in their bool_field column; user_ids that don't share a shared_field value, such as user_ids 2 and 7, should all have null in their bool_field column.) Clear as mud, right? ;)

This statement works:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET bool_field = (CASE
                       WHEN user_id = 4 THEN 'Y'
                       ELSE NULL
                      END)
 WHERE shared_field = 'ghi'
   AND (SELECT COUNT(shared_field)
          FROM my_table
         WHERE shared_field = 'ghi') > 1;
```

The question: is there some way that I can accomplish this same thing without knowing the shared_field value in advance? For example (and this doesn't work, of course) - **Update**: "of course" means I know this doesn't work because it is not correct Oracle syntax! The point is to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET bool_field = (CASE
                       WHEN user_id = 4 THEN 'Y'
                       ELSE NULL
                      END)
 WHERE shared_field = (SELECT shared_field FROM my_table WHERE user_id = 4) as sharedVal
   AND (SELECT COUNT(shared_field)
          FROM my_table
         WHERE shared_field = sharedVal) > 1;
```

---

**Update**: this is a regular SQL statement - I can't use a stored procedure.

Comment: You could, using a before update trigger set all bool_Fields for the shared_field in question to null, then let the update process.  or just put this into a transaction procedure and call it the first step is to set them to null the second to update the one record. if problems roll it all back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rather than saying that something "doesn't work", it is generally helpful to tell us how it doesn't work.  The query you posted, for example, appears to have syntax errors (`as sharedVal` is invalid because you can't assign an alias to an expression you're computing in the `SELECT` list).  But it's not clear if "doesn't work" means that you're getting syntax errors (which we can relatively easily debug with the error message) or whether it means that the query runs but doesn't do what you want (which I would expect the query to do if the syntax errors were corrected) in which case knowing how the query isn't doing what you want would be helpful.

I would expect something like

```
UPDATE my_table a
   SET bool_field = (CASE WHEN user_id = 4 
                          THEN 'Y' 
                          ELSE NULL 
                      END)
 WHERE shared_field = (SELECT shared_field 
                         FROM my_table b
                        WHERE b.user_id = 4)
   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM my_table c
                WHERE a.shared_field = c.shared_field
                  AND a.user_id     != c.user_id )
```

to work assuming that `user_id` is the primary key.

Comment: I've updated my post to indicate that I am aware the 2nd example has syntax errors. I used it to illustrate what I was trying to do and thought the "of course" would clue people in that I knew this. Your code example looks like it should work. I'll try it out on Monday and let you know.

Comment: Yes, this did what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've worked on Oracle, so check to make sure that this query returns the list of records you want to update:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM my_table 
        WHERE shared_field = m.shared_field 
        HAVING COUNT(shared_field) > 1);
```

If so, then this should work:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET bool_field = (CASE
                       WHEN user_id = 4 THEN 'Y'
                       ELSE NULL
                      END)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM my_table 
        WHERE shared_field = m.shared_field 
        HAVING COUNT(shared_field) > 1);
```

You could also try this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE shared_field IN (SELECT shared_field 
        FROM my_table 
        GROUP BY shared_field
        HAVING COUNT(shared_field) > 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out on Monday and let you know. I'm not seeing, though, where it has any code indicating user_id 4's shared_field value specifically, as opposed to just any multiple occurrence of a given shared_field value?

Comment: Yes, this one gave me all of the user_id records that share a shared_field value with some other user_id - not just the list of users who share specifically user_id 4's shared_field value. Still, thanks for the response! This could come in handy for something else.